# What is the safe way to call Debug.Assert from C++ CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, assert

This blog does not recommend it:
http://blog.kalmbachnet.de/?postid=78

But I want to do it anyway. I suppose I need to wrap my Debug.Assert with some sort of `#if` or `#ifdef` or something like that. Also, does anyone have a good example of a Debug.Assert in `C++ CLI`?

Suppose I have the following variable: `String^ validationError = bldError.ToString();`
And now I wish to do something like:

```
#if (DEBUG)
Debug.Assert(false, "Got the following validation error:" + validationError);
#endif
```

How can I do it safely in `C++ CLI`, and are there additional gotchas to check for?

***EDIT:*** Based on the answers, I have come up with the following macro:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define CLIASSERT(condition, ...) System::Diagnostics::Debug::Assert(condition, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define CLIASSERT(condition, ...) // This macro will completely evaporate in Release.
#endif
```

And here is an example of usage:

```
String^ strValidationError = bldError.ToString();
CLIASSERT(false, L"Schema validation error: " + strValidationError);
```

Comment: Cool! So much for being a "macro noob" hey :)

Comment: @demoncodemonkey, the question now is - does the post from 2006 still apply? Are guards still needed?

Comment: Why not just use the CRT assert? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick one

```
#ifndef NDEBUG // or
#if !defined(NDEBUG) // or

#ifdef _DEBUG // or
#if defined(_DEBUG)
```

AFAIK `NDEBUG` is defined in the ISO C++ standard (also used to enable/disable the standard library's `assert` macro), whereas `_DEBUG` is Microsoft-specific.

(Of course C++/CLI is not ISO C++, but in this case it doesn't make a difference)

Comment: Thanks, I am a bit confused about NDEBUG. Do you have further references, as pertains to C++ CLI (a .Net language by Microsoft)?

Comment: The C++/CLI language is an extension to ISO/IEC C++ (see the C++/CLI standard aka. ECMA-372, chapter "1. Scope").
Now, the ISO/IEC C++ standard doesn't define the term "debug" or "debug build" in any way, but it does say that the effect of including <cassert> or <assert.h> does depend on the presence of a macro called NDEBUG. And since the standard library header files use "!defined(NDEBUG)", it should be the safest thing to use. Of course you can use just *any* macro you like, if you make sure it's always defined/not-defined properly for the type of build you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

The blog post is accurate.  Make it look like this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    Debug::Assert(...);
#endif
```

Comment: Yep and then make it a macro to change calling it to a one-liner.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey, thanks. How can I make a macro that would work with variable number of arguments? I am a macro noob.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert.aspx

Comment: I just realized that the post I referenced is a few years old. I wonder if `CLI C++` still has this limitation.

Comment: @Harnish: yes, I checked before I posted.  You could check too, just look at the IL with ildasm.exe.

Answer (score 2):

MS has documented this behaviour at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx -- put briefly, when you do a release build, a compiler may or may not disable Assert and other such methods marked with ConditionalAttribute. For example the C# compiler does disable them, C++/CLI compiler does not. Even though the blog post is fairly old, I'd find it unlikely that the situation would change, considering what it says at that MSDN page.